# Why is it considered OK to store both the password hash and salt in the same place?

Tags: security

Let's assume for each user, we store the user's password hash and a unique salt in the same table. For example, it looks like this:

```
user_email, sha256(raw_password+salt), salt
```

AFAIK, this is a conventional practice and considered safe because it prevents attacks using rainbow tables. The reasoning is since attackers don't have a precomputed list of `sha256(raw_password+salt)` they are forced to recompute this for every row, and this will take a lot of time.

But I don't understand the reasoning above. According to this [old post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/how-long-does-it-take-to-perform-a-single-sha256), one core can run `sha256` more than 20M times per second. Doesn't that make it trivial for attackers to just recompute `sha256(raw_password+salt)` for all rows if the entire `users` table is compromised?

Related:

[Is It okay to save user's salt in the same table as password hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372103/is-it-okay-to-save-users-salt-in-the-same-table-as-password-hash)

Comment: That is why passwords are hashed using a slow hash algorithm.

Comment: @JohnWu but one core can run more than `sha256` 20M times/s.

Comment: The key word is “slow.” [SHA256 is for message digests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624372/best-practice-for-hashing-passwords-sha256-or-sha512), not passwords. Use a slower hash for passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John notes, your example is incorrect:

```
user_email, sha256(raw_password+salt), salt
```

This is not a good way to store passwords. You should replace sha256 here with a Key Derivation Function (KDF) such as PBKDF2 or scrypt. Then it would be fine. A properly tuned KDF can get the hashing rate down to dozens a second or fewer, even on good hardware (there are various competing factors here because the attacker doesn't have the same language and hardware restrictions you likely do, but even in the worst cases this value can be kept very low in cryptographic terms).

But even if you used sha256 here, it would be dramatically stronger than an unsalted hash. It makes every hash different. This means that if multiple people have the same password (very common), then breaking one doesn't break all users having the same password. This protects against rainbow tables, and particularly protects people who have very common passwords (password, dragon, mustang, etc.)

But it also protects against other password-collision attacks. For example, say I want to know Alice's password, and I can see it has the same hash as Bob. I now know that tricking either of them into revealing their password through some means will reveal both of their passwords.

> Doesn't that make it trivial for attackers to just recompute sha256(raw_password+salt) for all rows if the entire users table is compromised?

This is thinking about the problem backwards. If the attacker knew `raw_password`, then yes, this would be trivial. But that's exactly the thing the attacker does not know (and if they did, they wouldn't need to do any hashing). So the attacker must make a full search of each row of the database, which even with just a single SHA-256 is quite slow.

There are approximately 96 characters you can easily type on most English keyboards. The complete space of those for an 8-character string is 96^8 or about 7x10^15. At 20M per second, that's about 360M seconds or roughly 11 CPU-years per row. That's not an impossible space to crack, but it's still not fast. (Obviously there are many thing pushing in both directions; users don't choose passwords randomly, but they also aren't limited to 8 characters. This computation is just for illustration.)

A key take-away is that knowing the salt gives you no information at all about `sha256(salt+password)` if you don't know the password, too. That's a key feature of all cryptographic hashes (including the SHA series). If knowing part of the data gave you any information about the hash of the entire data, then that would tell us that the hash isn't secure.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, I conveniently forgot the fact that the attacker didn't have access to the raw password.

Comment: `It makes every hash different` not exactly. We don't have a result, however, within a restricted input-output range say 2^20 to 2^20, I expect a collision.